# Microsoft Graph api Mail services with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph api to send and get mails in my Spring Boot Application,

I had used the dependencies of graph api like

```
         <dependency>
             <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
             <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
             <version>3.5.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <!-- This dependency is only needed if you are using the TokenCrendentialAuthProvider -->
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

In code my imports are

```
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.BodyType;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.EmailAddress;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.ItemBody;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Message;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Recipient;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.UserSendMailParameterSet;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.MessageCollectionPage;
```

Error coming in code at

```
ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET).tenantId(TENANT_GUID).build();
    
    TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(SCOPES, clientSecretCredential);


    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( tokenCredentialAuthProvider ).buildClient();
    

    MessageCollectionPage messagesPage = graphClient.me().messages()
            .buildRequest()
            .select("Sender,Subject")
            .top(10)
            .get();
```

I am getting a error like this in code.

```
 (DirectJDKLog.java:175) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/ldesk] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBuilder.build(IdentityClientBuilder.java:113) ~[azure-identity-1.2.5.jar:?]
    at com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential.<init>(ClientSecretCredential.java:50) ~[azure-identity-1.2.5.jar:?]
    at com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder.build(ClientSecretCredentialBuilder.java:62) ~[azure-identity-1.2.5.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using microsoft-graph 3.4.0, you cannot use microsoft-graph-auth to create an IAuthenticationProvider object.

[preview](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth#23-get-a-httpclient-object-and-make-a-call):

```
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT_GUID, NATIONAL_CLOUD);

IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .buildClient();

User user = graphClient.users(user_id).buildRequest().get();
```

[New version](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java#22-create-an-iauthenticationprovider-object):

First, add `azure-identity` in Pom.xml.

```
ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .tenantId(tenant)
        .build();

TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);

GraphServiceClient graphClient =
  GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
    .buildClient();

User me = graphClient.users(user_id).buildRequest().get();
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: IGraphServiceClient wont work in microsoft-graph Version 3.4.0

Comment: microsoft-graph-auth does not support the new version. Please see my update.

Comment: Hi Pamela Peng,
Can you share me the working example with latest version in a Git.

Comment: I have shared the code about getting graphClient, doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#ClientCredentialsProvider). Maybe You could refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java.

Comment: Hi, @HARISH. Is there any update? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: It had not fixed .
can you help on this new error.


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient
 at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBuilder.build(IdentityClientBuilder.java:113) ~[azure-identity-1.2.5.jar:?]
 at com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential.<init>(ClientSecretCredential.java:50) ~[azure-identity-1.2.5.jar:?]
 at com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder.build(ClientSecretCredentialBuilder.java:62) ~[azure-identity-1.2.5.jar:?]

Comment: Please edit your code in the issue. I can't reproduce it with my code.

Comment: Edited, Can you please check this now

Comment: Sorry, I have a similar code as yours but cannot reproduce it. My pom.xml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2vGh.png. You could try to reload the maven repository. And there is an error in your code, you cannot use **me()** when using ClientSecretCredential, because it is based on an application without a user. You can use `users(user_id)` instead.

Comment: Hi Pamela Peng,  I had posted my error after adding that pom which u had suggested. please check it once

Comment: Thank U Very much @Pamela Peng